# Getting a blank page in Crystal report after Migration of my application to Windows server 2012

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, iis-8, windows-server-2012

Hi I have migrated my application from Windows server 2008R2 IIS7 to windows server 2012 IIS8 . but now my crystal report is not working it is just showing a blank page. My Application is on .NET2.0 yes i know its weird ,

what i have done on New VM

1) Installed CRRedist2005_X64.exe on server 2012.

2)I copied the aspnet_client and crystalreportviewer12 folder and give full permession to it and also create a virtual directory for this.

3) added a crystal report image handler in the handler mapping of IIS

4)Added a application pool for my application with Managed Pipeline Mode = "Classic" and Identity = "LocalSystem" i have also tried it with other attributes.

4) this is what i have in my web.config regarding crystal report

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
<sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
<section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null" />
<section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
<section name="printControl" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null" />
</sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<compilation debug="true">
<assemblies>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></assemblies>

</compilation>

<httpHandlers >
<add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />

</httpHandlers>

<businessObjects>
<crystalReports>
<rptBuildProvider>
<add embedRptInResource="true" />
</rptBuildProvider>
<crystalReportViewer>
<add key="ResourceUri" value="/crystalreportviewers13" />
</crystalReportViewer>
</crystalReports>
</businessObjects>
```

I don't know what else i have to do... Please help me in this

Comment: check if there's any javascript errors in the browser, e.g. in Developer Tools or Chrome Console. If there's a 'bobj not defined' error then permissions or path aren't right to the crystal js files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I migrated my web site, try for a long time until I found a solution, I changed project properties of the virtual directory,  I set this property and works, maybe works for you.

Image:

[image]